# Nginx experiencing 502 gateway errors when accessing my site on debian 10 + virtualmin

Tags: nginx, virtualmin

Debian 10
Nginx

nginx error log
I’m experiencing 502 gateway errors when accessing my site from time to time.

Ubuntu 20.04, Nginx, PHP-FPM 7.4, Virtualmin, Cloudflare

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P4nu2i9D)

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d [pastepin](https://pastebin.com/4wMahQep)

nginx error log

```
2021/01/02 17:14:00 [error] 56540#56540: *248074 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.114.110.89, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
2021/01/02 17:14:26 [error] 56540#56540: *248088 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.165.247, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/index.php"
2021/01/02 17:15:14 [error] 56540#56540: *248098 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.134.121, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com"
2021/01/02 17:15:43 [error] 56540#56540: *248109 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.114.110.89, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/site-available
default

```
##
# You should look at the following URL’s in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# Getting Started | NGINX
# Pitfalls and Common Mistakes | NGINX
# Nginx/DirectoryStructure - Debian Wiki
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/site-available
mydomailname.com.conf

```
server {
server_name mydomailname.com www.mydomailname.com;
listen 2xx.19x.x.xx;
root /home/mydomailname/public_html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomailname.com_access_log;
error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomailname.com_error_log;
fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomailname/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mydomailname/public_html;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
location ~ .php(/|$) {
try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
}
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
listen 2xx.1xx.xx.xx:443 default ssl;
ssl_certificate /home/mydomailname/ssl.cert;
ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomailname/ssl.key;
}
```